# python selenium: cannot click invisible element

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape the Google News page in the following way:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from pprint import pprint


base_url = 'https://www.google.com/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/vincent/wintergreen/chromedriver') ## change here to your location of the chromedriver
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(base_url)


input = driver.find_element_by_id('lst-ib')
input.send_keys("brexit key dates timetable schedule briefing")

click = driver.find_element_by_name('btnK')
click.click()

news = driver.find_element_by_link_text('News')
news.click()

tools = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Tools')
tools.click()

time.sleep(1)

recent = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.hdtb-mn-hd[aria-label=Recent]')
recent.click()

# custom = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Custom range...')
custom = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li#cdr_opt span')
custom.click()

from_ = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#cdr_min')
from_.send_keys("9/1/2018")

to_ = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#cdr_max')
to_.send_keys("9/2/2018")

time.sleep(1)

go_ = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form input[type="submit"]')
print(go_)
pprint(dir(go_))
pprint(go_.__dict__)
go_.click()
```

This script manage to enter search terms, switch to the news tab, open the custom time period tab, fill in start and end date, but fails to click on the 'Go' button after that point.

From the `print` and `pprint` statement at the end of the script, I can deduct that it does find the 'go' button succesfully, but is somehow unable to click on it. The error displays as `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible`

Could anyone experienced with Selenium have a quick run at it and give me hints as why it returns such error?

Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evaluating the css using developer tools in chrome yields 4 elements.

[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PajJT.png)

use the following css instead:

```
go_ = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#cdr_frm > input.ksb.mini.cdr_go')
```

Comment: thx a lot! Briefly can you tell me how, from the console, you could isolate `#cdr_frm` as the proper parent to reference?

Comment: Right click element -> Inspect -> Developer Tool Opens -> In the Elements tab -> right click highlighted element -> Right Click -> Copy -> Copy Selector